# What does this LINQ query do in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm still trying to pickup LINQ, and was wondering if anyone can shed some light on what this LINQ query do.

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, datatimepicker1.Value.Subtract(datatimepicker1.Value).Days + 1)
.Select(d => datatimepicker2.Value.AddDays(d));
```

Comment: It creates a bunch of `DateTime`s that are one day apart, starting from `datatimepicker2.Value` and ending at `datatimepicker1.Value`.

Comment: @Sweeper - why not post it as an answer? That way we can all see from the dashboard that the Q has an answer (so we can focus on a q that has no answer), the OP can accept it, (and we can then really see we don't need to come in here), plus you get the points and Tek gets some positive rep. Answering questions with answers = win win all round. Answering with comments = waste of time for many people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing what this LINQ query is *trying to do* and what it *does* are actually two different things.

- `datatimepicker1.Value.Subtract(datatimepicker1.Value)` is always going to give you an empty timespan, so the `.Days` property from that will always give you zero.
- `Enumerable.Range(0, 0+1)` will give you an IEnumerable with a single value in it: `0`.
- `AddDays(0)` will give you back the original time.

So effectively this whole LINQ statement is the same as:

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = new[]{datatimepicker2.Value};
```

But if we try to read the mind of the author, we could guess that they probably didn't mean to make an overly complicated query for that purpose. Maybe what they meant to do was something like this:

```
var startDate = datatimepicker2.Value;
var endDate = datatimepicker1.Value
var daysBetweenTimes = endDate.Subtract(startDate).Days;
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, daysBetweenTimes + 1)
    .Select(d => startDate.AddDays(d));
```

In this case, `Enumerable.Range` would yield a series of numbers `{0, 1, 2, ...}` for how many days there are between those dates, and the `Select` would give you a series of dates that represent the offset of those times from the start time. This would give you a collection including one entry for each date from `datatimepicker2`'s value until `datatimepicker1`'s value.

Comment: Maybe add `IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = Enumerable.Range(0, datatimepicker1.Value.Subtract(datatimepicker2.Value).Days + 1)
.Select(d => datatimepicker2.Value.AddDays(d));` assuming `datatimepicker2.Value` is the lower value as what it should probably be doing?

Comment: @Knoop: That's what I'm thinking too. See my update.

Comment: @CaiusJard: Yup. Fixed it.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that was it! It was to have a list of dates between the 2 dates. How can i change the LINQ query so instead of 1 day for e.g. it would be 5 days?

Comment: @TekC2MSIS: I'm not totally clear on what you mean. You want a list of every fifth day from the start date until the end date? Do you want the first entry to be the start date, still? What if the end date doesn't land on a fifth day? Would you include the end date anyway?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior For e.g, i need a list of datetimes of the end of everymonth between 2 dates. Imagine that startdate is 01/01 and enddate is 12/04. The list must contain: 01/01; 28/02; 31/03; 12/04

Comment: Instead of AddDays(d) you could do AddDays(5*d) or AddMonths(d)